# calculating the sum of sub-array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm not an English speaker so please don't judge :)

I need your help with an exercise please.

The program gets an array size and a number from the user.

The number is the target - there's a loop that searches for that number.

It should appear at least two times in the array, and the program should calculate the sum of integers between the two farthest numbers from left to right.

for example:
the user wanted 10 integers in the array:

4, 6, 0, 12, 55, 2, 0, 12, 7, 12

the program sums all the numbers from the most left 12, to the most right 12.

The operation: 12+55+2+0+12+7+12 = 100

I don't even know where to start, and will really appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: you have to code it by yourself, or at least try. we can help you if you stuck in something but you have to try something and we will help you. at least start ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the logic as follows (wont help you with the code)

1. Iterate (go through all elements 1 by 1) through array till you reach first position of the number given. Mark that as start (For e.g as above, 3 will be start counting from 0)
2. From start move forward in array till you find another match. hold that position as end point. (7 for above array)
3. Continue from end point in array again till you meet another number or reach the end of array. In case of end reached, jump to Step 6. (9 for above array)
4. In case of another number, mark this one as end point (change 7 to 9)
5. Repeat Step 3
6. Now calculate the sum of all nos from start till end (from 3 to 9)

Done !

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try :)

Comment: Plz mark the answer as accepted if you find it ok.